# openCV look up table for 16CU1

Tags: c++, opencv, lookup-tables

I need to replace the value of a Mat 8UC1 [0,255] to values of a cv::Mat lookUpTable(1, 256, CV_16UC1); I check un this OpenCV [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#the-core-function) an explanation which is the fastest method, however,  when Im checking the assigned values of the LUT in each position im only sabing 8-bits so Im lossing the other 8-bits. This is the source code:

```
  unsigned short int zDTableHexa[256]={0};
  .... get the values...
  cv::Mat lookUpTable(1, 256, CV_16UC1);
  uchar* p = lookUpTable.data;
  for( int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
      p[i] = zDTableHexa[i];
      cout<<(int)p[i]<<":"<<zDTableHexa[i]<<sizeof(p[i])<<":"<<sizeof(zDTableHexa[i])<<endl;
  }
```

The printing result are:

> 104:872
> 101:869
> 97:865
> 93:861
> 90:858
> 86:854
> 83:851
> 80:848
> 76:844
> 73:841
> 70:838
> 66:834
> 63:831

When I check in binary is only the first 8-bits.
I understand that the pointer is UCHAR(8bits) but how I can assign the full value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
unsigned short* p = (unsigned short*) lookUpTable.data;
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV LUT is working just with CV_8U, so what you can do is splitting the numbers in 3, that is 3x CV_8U, or CV_8UC3. But you cannot have more than 256 elements in the LUT and not other values than 0..255 as index.

In other words, you can parse `uchar`s to `uchar`s or `uchar`s to `float`s: CV_8UC1 -> CV_8UC1 or CV_8UC1 -> CV_8UC3 (I did not tried it whit CV_8UC4, it could work).

For getting the elements of CV_8UC3 check [cv::Vec3b](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec)

---

I found [this](http://answers.opencv.org/question/51356/lookup-table-for-16-bit-images/), that might interest you